# Reset TextBox.Background to default in WPF so it still gets updated when system settings change

Tags: wpf, textbox, colors, background, systemcolors

I have a TextBox that I wish to reset its **Background** property to its default value after changing it to a different colour.

I have tried setting it to `SystemColors.WindowBrush`, but then, if the Display Settings are updated to change this value, it doesn't get dynamically reflected in the TextBox (it does normally if **TextBox.Background** hasn't been touched).

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand of WPF's binding system, setting it to `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue` should revert it to WPF figuring out what to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

for Wpf this line work for me:

```
TextBox1.ClearValue(TextBox.BackgroundProperty);
```